# Is it possible to digitally sign an email twice?

Tags: email, digital-signature

User A encrypts an email with the public key of user B and digitally signs it. User B receives this message and decrypts it. B wants to forward it to user C, encrypts it with C's public key and signs it again.

Is it possible to send user C an email was that digitally signed by both user A and B? Or can an email only have one digital signature?

Comment: Note that encrypting data is quite different from digitally signing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the order of operations. If A signed the email and then encrypted it with B's public key, then when B decrypts the email, the signature is still valid, and thus B can sign the email signed by A and encrypt it with C's public key. When C receives the email, they can decrypt the email and check both signatures and all is well.

If however A encrypted the email before signing, there would be no valid signature left after B decrypts the email. And so there would be no way to have C verify A's signature.

As cremefraiche points out clearsigning the message before encrypting will allow both signatures to be verified.

Comment: Well put. I think you gave a better explanation than I did.

Comment: You could still compare the first encrypted and then signed message with a "self-encrypted" version of the unencrypted message of A, as for this encryption the public key of B is used. You would then have to check the signature hash of your self-encrypted version with A's signature. But this seems rather impractical to me...